# Symfony cli install without scoop

Tags: symfony, symfony-cli

Is there a way to install symfony cli without scoop ?

I just like the general idea of keeping things vanilla without installing countless addons.

Comment: Yeah, of course. Use any way described at https://symfony.com/download